# Prepare windows for power failure

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, acpi

In my scenario i have Windows system that can be notified about a power failure
up to 200ms ***before*** the power failure (The UPS already failed in this scenario).

As this won't be enough to shutdown Windows properly, is there anything i can do to prevent damage to the file system?

I know i can do `sync`. But will this be enough to prevent damage?
I could also send a ACPI command to the windows. But i didn't find any that will put windows in a ready-for-powerfail state. Am i wrong about this?

Further system information:
2 CPU cores, 2GB RAM, SSD drive.

Comment: 200ms is not an awful lot of time for spinning disks.  If a sync can write, thats probably the best you will be able to do.  Try use a filesystem with journalling.  (If you use NTFS enable journalling)

Comment: Your UPS should be able to send a signal 5 minutes before power will run out, at which point it should initiate a graceful shutdown, as well as sounding that awful aural alert.

Comment: yes it should, and probably also will. But i have to evaluate this scenario.

Comment: The answer is to get the UPS working properly or get a working UPS.  That's their purpose.  200 ms isn't enough time to do anything.

Comment: Get WIndows to flush the cache to disk - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405868/how-to-invalidate-the-file-system-cache/7701908#7701908